# Contract functions not triggered

Tags: contract-development, contract-debugging, contract-invocation

My contract deployed on address

```
 0x63788a3eace0d77c5573787e3f9c9515c246d0e6
```

Is not getting executed via Mist browser.

I have tried execute NewPoll function that requires 4 fields

- text 32 bytes I passed 4d6172656b205369702020132046534520726573756c7473
- options bytes32[] - passed [0x506173736564,0x4661696c6564]
- voters bytes32[] - passed empty arraz []
- deadline uint - passed 1464739199

However I cannot see any changes to the public object p in Mist browser

Contract code available at: https://github.com/mareksip/PureVote/blob/master/purevote.sol

Thank you for any prior assist.

Answer (score 2):

Based on the transactions sent to that address, I'd say you probably aren't specifying a high enough gas limit. ~21,000 is the minimum necessary to send ether, and it looks like all three of your transactions only supplied around that much. Storage state changes are more expensive.